# Database agnostic now() datetime function?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, sqlite

I've the following condition in one of my model which works for mysql.

```
with_scope :find => { :conditions => "starts_at <= now() AND ends_at >= now()" }
```

But I get error on the sqlite3 test database coz that now() is specific to mysql db only.
What would be a db agnostic way for that now() function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` is standard in SQL92, and should be sufficiently cross-platform.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use ruby to give you the current timestamp and not rely on the database. eg.

```
current_ts = Time.now
with_scope :find => { :conditions => ["starts_at <= ? AND ends_at >= ?", current_ts, current_ts] }
```

I personally prefer this as the timestamp can be modified easily (plus or minus an hour etc.) without having to write sql which may not work in all versions.

Comment: I edited your post:

Two things: 1) Don't need zone, it's automatically converted to UTC unless you purposefully set it not to be 2) don't need to to_s(:db) it, that is also done automatically.